# B.C. for time-decaying delta barrier inside an infinite well

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions, dirac-delta-distributions

So let's say I have an infinite well with walls up at $x=-L$ and $x=L$. Suppose that inside the well, there is a time-dependent potential

$$ V(x,t)= \alpha_0\delta{(x)}f(t) $$

where $f(t)$ is a monotonically decreasing function. Then the time-dependent Schrodinger equation in the region $x \, \in  \,[-L,L]$ is then

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\partial_{x}^2\Psi(x,t)+\alpha_0\delta{(x)}f(t)\Psi(x,t) = i\hbar \partial_t \Psi(x,t). $$

Am I right in assuming that these are the boundary conditions? Is there anything I'm missing?

1. $\Psi(-L,t)=0$ and $\Psi(L,t)=0$
2. At any $t=\textrm{constant}$, $$\Delta(\partial_x \Psi(x,t)) = \partial_x \Psi(x,t) \vert_{+q} - \partial_x \Psi(x,t) \vert_{-q} = \frac{-2m\alpha_0}{\hbar^2}\Psi(x=0,t).$$
3. As $t\rightarrow \infty$, $\Psi(x,t) \rightarrow \Psi_{ISQ}(x,t)$. Where ISQ stands for the infinite square well

Answer (score 0):

If you have a time dependent potential, you need to solve the *time dependent* Schroedinger equation --  and the solution is unlikely  to become a solution of the time-independent infinite square well problem as $t\to \infty$.

Comment: So that removes condition 3? How about the first 2 conditions?

Comment: They look Ok. WSavfunction has to be continuous at $x=0$ also